# Error (Klocwork): '_M_dataplus._M_p' might be used uninitialized in this function

Tags: linux, c++11, stl

**'Klocwork'** profiller generate the error ['it.second.name_._M_dataplus._M_p' might be used uninitialized in this function.] in following code section.

```
    class Test {
            public:
                    Test() { }

                    Test(std::string str) {
                            name = str;
                            cout <<"Test::Test object: " <<name <<endl;
                    }

                    ~Test() {
                            cout <<"Test::~Test object: " <<name <<endl;
                    }

                    string getName() {
                            return name;
                    }
            private:
                    string name;
    };

    class MapHandler {
            private:
                    map<int, Test> myMap;

            public:
                    void MapFiller();
                    void MapDisplay();
    };

    void MapHandler::MapFiller() {               
            Test obj1("Obj1");
            Test obj2("Obj2");
            Test obj3("Obj3");       
            myMap[1] = obj1;
            myMap[2] = obj1;
            myMap[3] = obj3;
    }

    void MapHandler::MapDisplay() {               
            map<int, Test> tmpMap;
            for(auto it : myMap) {
                    cout <<"object: " << it.second.getName() <<endl;
                    tmpMap[it.first] = it.second;
            } **//Error Line**
    }
```

But in simple compilation using [g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror test.cpp] it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the default constructor:

```
Test()
{
    name = "";
}
```